# Please tell me where does $c_1\cos(\omega t) +c_2\sin(\omega t)$ come from in this context?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Would anyone tell me please, where is the $c_1\cos(\omega t) +c_2\sin(\omega t)$ coming from? Please see the yellow highlighted part of the image.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you heard of Eulers formula?

It says that

$$e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$$

Now assuming you are familiar with the usual form involving exponential, it is simply this formula applied to that.

For more explanation, see [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171222072434/http://mathforum.org/mathimages/index.php/Simple_Harmonic_Motion)